# Arrow from the middle of one row to the middle of the second row

Tags: tikz-arrows

I need to create a table with several rows, and then put a curved arrow pointing from the middle of the first row to the middle of the second row. Here is a hand-drawn picture showing what I have in mind (the grid is there to help visual the situation; I do NOT want the grid in the final product):

[image]

I can get the arrow using e.g. \rcurvearrowdown in the MnSymbol font package, but I have no idea how to put the arrow where I want without using e.g. tikz. Is there an more elementary way to accomplish this?

Comment: Define 'elementary'. If you mean 'fundamental' then yes, there will be more fundamental ways to do it. If you mean 'easier', 'less effortful' etc. then probably not. To put this another way, what do you have against using Ti*k*Z or similar?

Comment: Is the distance between the rows always the same or does it need to be dynamic depending on the height of each row?

Comment: @cfr:  By "elementary" I mean e.g. do this within the  context of \begin{array}\end{array}.  For example, the standard \\ avances from one row to another; I was wondering if there is a way to advance half a row.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel:   Ideally I would like the distance to adjust dynamically based on the height of the rows.

Comment: So why not the `tikzmark` solution? Note that you haven't provided any code which might provide a clue as to how you want to use this. A minimal example containing e.g. an `array` would make it easier for people to understand your question and help if interested.

Comment: Why don't you add the code to your question, which worked and which you'd like to improve? Makes things easier for all of us. Thank you